# Как правильно менять значение в инстансе, из компонента во vue.js

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

Всем доброго дня.
Изучаю компоненты во vue.js.

Никак не могу понять, как правильно изменять data в инстансе через компонент.

Написал простое взаимодействие: инстанс + компонент. компонент меняет булево значение в инстансе на противоположное. Но при этом понимаю, что написал костыльно.

Прошу помочь - показать, как делать правильно. Заранее спасибо.

[JSfiddle с примером](https://jsfiddle.net/VeVeO/wgkyj94h/5/)

```js
Vue.component('show-div-button',{
 template:'<button v-on:click="hide">Show/hide</button>',
  methods: {
   hide: function(){
     if (sample.showDiv == true) {
       this.$root.$emit('hide', false);
      } else {
       this.$root.$emit('hide', true);
      }
     
    }
  }
}); 

const sample = new Vue  ({ 
  el: '.sample',
  data: {
    showDiv: true
  },
  created() {
    this.$root.$on('hide', (hide) => {
     this.showDiv = hide;
    })
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div class="sample" style="text-align: center">
   <div v-if="showDiv" style="background: yellow">
    showDiv
  </div>
  <show-div-button></show-div-button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
Vue.config.productionTip = false; // Отрубаем сообщения
Vue.config.devtools = false;      // Не нужны они

Vue.component('show-div-button',{
 template:'<button @click="$emit(\'change-div\')">Show/hide</button>'
}); 

const sample = new Vue  ({ 
  el: '.sample',
  data: {
    showDiv: true
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>

<div class="sample" style="text-align: center">
   <div v-if="showDiv" style="background: yellow">
    showDiv
  </div>
  <show-div-button @change-div="showDiv = !showDiv"></show-div-button>
</div>
```